# How to center a tikzpicture in the page?

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment

I am trying to center a tikzpicture, I had a look at several questions here that tell me to use either

```
\centering
```

or

```
\begin{center}
```

But to no avail : I would like the graph of the function to appear in the middle of the page, but it is still aligned left.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{exam}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{sansmathfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, bottom=0.5cm, top=0.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{parskip}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\newtheorem{exo}{Exercice}
\newtheorem{que}{Question}
\makeatother

\date{}
%%%% fin du préambule, on passe au contenu : tout le texte entre
%%%% \begin{document} et \end{document} 

\begin{document}
\begin{exo}[De la représentation graphique au tableau de valeurs]
La courbe ci-dessous est la représentation de la fonction f dans un repère orthonormé 
\newline

{\centering

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=middle,
        grid=major,
        xmin=-7.1,
        xmax=7.1,
        ymin=-2.1,
        ymax=7.1,
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$,
        xtick={-7,-6,...,7},
        ytick={-7,-6,...,7},
        scale=1.5,
        transform shape,
        ticklabel style={
                    fill=white
                },
        tick style={very thick},
        axis equal image,
        legend style={
        at={(rel axis cs:0,1)},
        anchor=north west,draw=none,inner sep=0pt,fill=gray!10}
        ]
        \addplot[color=red] coordinates {
            (-7.10000,-2.111005)
    (-7.00000,-1.000000)
    (-6.00000,3.982684)
    (-5.00000,3.072727)
    (-4.00000,1.000000)
    (-3.00000,-0.156566)
    (-2.00000,-0.000000)
    (-0.00000,1.986869)
    (1.00000,2.406926)
    (2.00000,2.000000)
    (3.00000,1.000000)
    (4.00000,0.000000)
    (5.00000,-0.336364)
    (6.00000,0.256854)
    (7.00000,1.000000)
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{exo}

\end{document}
```

[image: The result of my code]

How can I center the tikzpicture?

Comment: Maybe you can use a float environment, i.e. `figure` here. Wrap the tikzpicture inside `begin{figure}[htbp]` and `end{figure}`, and place the `\centering` inside `figure` environment.

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE! Next time please make your code minimal, i. e. don't include code unrelated to the question (see PS in my answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how exactly you are using `center`, but this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{exam}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{sansmathfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, bottom=0.5cm, top=0.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{parskip}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\newtheorem{exo}{Exercice}
\newtheorem{que}{Question}
\makeatother

\date{}
%%%% fin du préambule, on passe au contenu : tout le texte entre
%%%% \begin{document} et \end{document} 

\begin{document}
\begin{exo}[De la représentation graphique au tableau de valeurs]
La courbe ci-dessous est la représentation de la fonction f dans un repère orthonormé 

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=middle,
        grid=major,
        xmin=-7.1,
        xmax=7.1,
        ymin=-2.1,
        ymax=7.1,
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$,
        xtick={-7,-6,...,7},
        ytick={-7,-6,...,7},
        scale=1.5,
        transform shape,
        ticklabel style={
                    fill=white
                },
        tick style={very thick},
        axis equal image,
        legend style={
        at={(rel axis cs:0,1)},
        anchor=north west,draw=none,inner sep=0pt,fill=gray!10}
        ]
        \addplot[color=red] coordinates {
            (-7.10000,-2.111005)
    (-7.00000,-1.000000)
    (-6.00000,3.982684)
    (-5.00000,3.072727)
    (-4.00000,1.000000)
    (-3.00000,-0.156566)
    (-2.00000,-0.000000)
    (-0.00000,1.986869)
    (1.00000,2.406926)
    (2.00000,2.000000)
    (3.00000,1.000000)
    (4.00000,0.000000)
    (5.00000,-0.336364)
    (6.00000,0.256854)
    (7.00000,1.000000)
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{exo}

\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

**P.S.** If you are using modern TeX distribution, you do not need `inputenc`. If you want to use `\centering`, don't forget to execute `\par` at the end of a group:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{exam}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, bottom=0.5cm, top=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newtheorem{exo}{Exercice}

\begin{document}
\begin{exo}[De la représentation graphique au tableau de valeurs]
La courbe ci-dessous est la représentation de la fonction f dans un repère orthonormé 

{\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\par}
\end{exo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not what OP's asking. `I would like the graph of the function to appear in the middle of the page, but it is *still aligned left*.`

Comment: @SebGlav Yes, and I've provided the solution to make the graph appear in the center.

Answer (score 2):

Your example do not work because you are reverting the `\centering` by closing a group *before* finishing the paragraph. If you change your

```latex
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

with

```latex
    \end{tikzpicture}%

}
```

(notice the blank line, ending the paragraph) the centering will work. I also added the `%` to avoid having a spurious space at the end of the picture...

*Unrelated*: read the warnings and a a `\pgfplotsset{compat=X}` after loading the library, or you will have problems in the future...